# How do I store and access my third party API keys with AWS

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, amazon-web-services, encryption

I have an existing ASP.NET/ C# website that I am looking to migrate to AWS. 
I currently store all 3rd party API tokens/credentials in my web.config file in an encrypted section.

The encryption is done via the normal aspnet_regiis command similar to this:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

That all works very well.

Moving to the AWS world I understand I could do the same thing using the web.config file but I wanted to know if there is a better, more appropriate way to do this.

The AWS Key Management Service sounds like it is meant to solve this problem but from what I can ascertain it is really just for storing your AWS master keys.

I've seen that people have used the master keys to encrypt a text file that is uploaded to the AWS web server and then using the master keys to decrypt the file when it is required. That file could contain a list of third party keys and so would be one way to solve the problem.

What I am trying to understand, but failing to is, is that the correct way to do it (i.e. storing the 3rd party keys in a text/json/xml file and encrypting with the AWS master key and storing on the server and querying as and when necessary) or is there a way in AWS to enter each of my 3rd party keys into somewhere/something that the web application can query directly?

Comment: What I do is store credentials in an INI file on a secured S3 bucket, then download and parse during provisioning. eg s3://credentials-example-com/app1.ini. Only the instance itself and automatized users are given access to that bucket.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like what I have heard about previously but a bit more specific in terms storing the file in an S3 bucket instead of storing it with the actual website files. The AWS roles will allow me to secure access to that file and I can update the file independently of changing the website files. I'm starting to come around to that idea.

Comment: Work great really. Should I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two good choices for storing credentials for Amazon EC2 instances. Both are the Amazon recommended method. Do NOT store credentials on the EC2 instance, in your code or on S3.

1. Create an IAM role for your EC2 instance, assign desired permissions, assign this role to your instance. The Amazon SDKs will automatically extract these credentials. This is the easiest method.
2. Create your credentials in IAM, then use EC2 Parameter Store to store you credentials securely.

[IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

[The Right Way to Store Secrets using Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/the-right-way-to-store-secrets-using-parameter-store/)

Comment: When you say "The Amazon SDKs will automatically extract these credentials" what do you mean? Where I am entering the 3rd party keys that I have for the Amazon SDKs to extract from?

Comment: Now AWS Parameter Store sounds much more like the right way to do it. Some further research needed. Thank you. I'll mark your answer shortly.

Comment: AWS Parameter Store is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: When you create an IAM role and assign the role to the EC2 instance, the credentials are stored in the metadata for the instance. The AWS SKDs are written to search for credentials in the follow order: Environment variables, Profiles and then EC2 Role. The first link in my answer will provide more details on how EC2 Roles work. This is the method that I use most of the time. I often use Parameter Store also for DB credentials, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley So this works for storing arbitrary application passwords, secure tokens for later retrieval during provisioning etc?

Comment: Parameter Store does not care what you put into storage - within its storage limits.